# How to set Finish Location of flow to the community first page

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-community, redirect, finishlocation

I have two community pages. The first page is just a welcome page. The second page has the flow embedded in it. Once user clicks the flow "Finish" button, it takes user to the start of the flow, which is the second page on community. How do I configure the return url for flow to redirect to First page of community, afetr user clicks Finish button?

Comment: so, I presume you looked at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_internal_url_retURL.htm&type=5 ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes I did but where do I add this   /flow/flowName?retURL=url ?

Comment: I have embedded the flow in the community. Where do I add the return url?